# How can i execute a function after changing a react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I execute setState in class component, I can pass the callback to the last argument, and callback execute after changing State:

```
this.setState({}, () => { *execute after changing state* })
```

My example:

```
const foo = () => {
   setOpen(false); 
   bar(); // this function should be performed after completion setOpen changing, but setOpen is async func
}
```

Question: How to execute bar () immediately after the update of the hook through setOpen is completed with the false argument?

Answer (score 2):

You'd do it like this:

```
const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState( false );

useEffect(() => {

    if( !isOpen ) {

         bar();

    }

}, [ isOpen ]);
```

The `useEffect` hook is triggered once a change to `isOpen` is detected because it is listed in the dependencies for the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: But bar() will execute after first render, I need execute bar() after few `isOpen` changes

Comment: What do you mean "a few"?

Comment: @Enkei can you provide more information on what you want? This solution will run `bar()` every time `isOpen` changes to `false`.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle. isOpen hook is responsible for open Material-UI Dialog window. bar() is unmount Dialog component from parent component. I need to close dialog window by isOpen hook with default animations, and then unmount this component by bar() function

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle so, if I will use this answer, my dialog window component with `isOpen = false` will render, and then bar() will executed, and component unmount

Comment: Right, I've added my own answer to give you what I think you need.

Answer (score -1):

From what I've gathered, you're dealing with some animations upon your component closing and that `bar` is the function to unmount the component.

Technically what you'd be looking for (if the animation takes `500ms` to complete) is this:

```
// Add this line somewhere outside of your component, preferably in a helpers file.
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const foo = async () => {
   setOpen(false);
   await delay(500) // Change this value to match the animation time
   bar();
}
```

This should allow your animation to ru before unmounting the component.

Comment: What do you suggest? How is it a dirty hack?  If the OP has a CSS animation that's animating the component closing and then he wants to unmount it. How else would you wait for the CSS animation to complete before unkounting?